# Bad Layer in QGIS switching from PostGIS ST_DWithin from ST_Within

Tags: qgis, postgis

I can create a view in PostGIS using ST_Within and render it in QGIS without errors.

If I change to ST_DWithin (note the D) it creates a valid view in the database, but bad layers in QGIS.

This line works fine, no bad layers:
...cacities2014 d WHERE st_dwithin(c.geom, d.geom, 0.100) ...

This line causes the bad layers:
...cacities2014 d WHERE st_within(c.geom, d.geom) ...

Why would ST_DWithin have different characteristics in QGIS than ST_Within?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? QGIS sometimes struggle reloading changed layers. Could you provide any console messages, available from the bottom right icon of the main window?

Comment: I simply needed to add "DISTINCT ON" to my query. I was generating views with multiple id_pk's. Not surprisingly, this is covered in the manual at http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html.

Answer (score 1):

I simply needed to add "DISTINCT ON" to my query. I was generating views with multiple primary keys, and QGIS was balking at rendering a table with multiple primary keys. ST_Within (as opposed to ST_DWithin) was not creating multiple id_pk's so it was never a problem before.

Not surprisingly, this is covered in the manual at postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html